# terraform aws pass instance list from 1 module to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, terraform

I'm creating 2 instances in 1 module and I now need to attach those 2 instances to an ELB which is created using another module (same file) - is this possible without manually specifying them?

```
  module "instances" {
  source = "../../../../modules/ec2"

  ami                         = "ami...."
  number_of_instances         = 2
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
}

  module "elb" {
  source = "../../../../modules//elb"

  name = "some elb"
  instances = ["???"] #something like ["${module.ec2.instances.id}"]?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, define the output in your ec2 module:

```
output "instance_ids" {
  value = ["${aws_instance.web.*.id}"]
}
```

Note: the resource name `web` is an example. Please specify the actual resource name in the module.

Next, declare the list variable in your elb module:

```
variable "instances" {
  type = "list"
}
```

Finally, pass the output of the ec2 module to the elb module:

```
module "instances" {
  source = "../../../../modules/ec2"

  ami                         = "ami...."
  number_of_instances         = 2
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
}

module "elb" {
  source = "../../../../modules/elb"

  name = "some elb"
  instances = ["${module.instances.instance_ids}"]
}
```